# How to set a switch in android disabled and also have a grayish color so that user can understand this switch is disabled

Tags: android, kotlin, uiswitch

I tried

```
isEnabled = false 
isFocsable = false 
isClickabe = false 
isActivited = false
```

but nothing is giving that grayish color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make use of Material Switch from the Material Design Library . Add the material design dependency and make use of Switches from the Material Design library . The library automatically takes care of the scenario you have described . More information about the Switches by the Material Design library can be found here :
https://material.io/components/switches

You just have to include the dependency of Material Design and use the following in your xml file

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        ...
    />
```

Comment: Post your code and ellaborate on what does not work .

Comment: can you share screenshot of the same

Comment: Have you read the documentation provided as specially this part 
 -> https://material.io/components/switches/android#theming-switches

Comment: sorry, it did work, i was just getting multiply calls in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with the style. Like define a style in themes.xml

```
<style name="Switchtheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    
    <item name="colorControlActivated">Your color code</item>

    <!-- inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">Your color code
    </item>

   
    <item name="android:colorForeground">Your color code
    </item>
```

In XML

```
<Switch
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:checked="false"
            android:theme="@style/Switchtheme"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```